# Autoexpand vertically when user scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want a site that adds square div boxes sized 100px x 100px when the user scrolls down on the page. Inspiration: http://ohlandmusic.com/

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just code along these lines

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('body').append($('<div class="b100x100"/>'));
        //append more here
    }
}
```

this handler should be put in your page initialization code.

For better approaches, look here: http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

There are also plenty of different answers to similar questions on SO.